# Symfony2: Twig blocks doesn't show up

Tags: php, symfony

I'm learning symfony2 and I came across this problem.

I have index.html.twig in my "ShopBundle", which look like this:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}


    <div class="container">

        <h2>Index template</h2>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            {% block login %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            {% block profile%}{% endblock %}
        </div>

    </div>


{% endblock %}
```

as you can see I want to display login form and some user info in my index.

**Here is my login form twig**

```
{% extends "FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

{% block login %}
    {% block fos_user_content %}

        .....

    {% endblock fos_user_content %}
{% endblock login %}
```

**and here is my profile info twig**

```
{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

{% block profile %}
  {% block fos_user_content %}

    ...

  {% endblock fos_user_content %}
{% endblock profile %}
```

**And here is my file structure**

[image]

**So why it's not working? What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible to do it like this?
Thank you very much for all advices.**

Comment: Do you have any errors?  and show me your controller

Comment: You’re just creating blocks with nothing in them. So it is absolutely normal if nothing shows up. `{% block foo %}{% endblock foo %}` is just to create a block called `foo`. Nothing more. Maybe what you want is including templates. If so, you can look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#including-other-templates

Comment: Ok I see.. so is it possible to include blocks created in other bundle?

Comment: Yes, you can use blocks created in other bundles, just extend it. `{% extends('FooExampleBundle::layout.html.twig') %}` like normal.